How do I complete Use Daily Adventure Incense to help catch 10 Pokemon quest in An Intruiging Incense Part 2?
I used the Adventure Incense and caught Pokemon with the ring around them but the counter doesn't go up.

So, any update with your problem?

It's hard to tell, here's what Niantic suggests:

I caught 10 Pokémon, but they didn’t count towards the “Use Daily Adventure Incense to help catch 10 Pokémon"
When using the Daily Adventure Incense, make sure you’re catching Pokémon that are attracted to it to complete this task. These Pokémon appear on the Map with a blue swirl and have a small blue incense icon over the Pokémon’s CP on the catch encounter screen.
Please ensure you are using the blue Daily Adventure Incense to complete this task. You can locate this Incense in your Bag or by tapping on it when it appears on the top right corner of your Map. Using the regular green Incense will not help to complete this task.


From Niantic FAQs page.
EDIT:
According to Reddit, it looks like a bug and there's a fix:

For other players with the same problem: I solved by first using normal incense and then activating daily adventure incense after the first one ran out.

These are the different Incence icons: green is the normal one, blue is the Adventure one.


i know but it doesnt work (i think)

@PianoCat98 I updated my answer, try that too

can you show a picture of what. the symbol looks like cus ive tried both but it didnt work

@PianoCat98 done

ive never seen that before i think my phone is broken apart from the screen being totally broken and only the samsung pen being able to use the phone and part of the screen is black
